# How can I configure Ubuntu to report its hostname to windows?

Tags: server, windows, networking, dns, hostname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access Ubuntu Server by host name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2631/access-ubuntu-server-by-host-name)

How can I configure Ubuntu server to report its hostname in such a way that typing `http://thehostname/` in a web browser will connect to apache running on my Windows machine.

This question is not about configuring apache, but more specifically getting `myhostname` to resolve to the machine's IP address from a computer running Windows.

Extra information: I am running Ubuntu Server 10.04.1 32bit with minimal changes from default. The most notable change is enabling ufw.