# Name resolution on home LAN?

Tags: networking, dns, hostname

Is there an easy way to allow my other computers to resolve my hostname over the network without having them edit their hosts files or their DNS settings? Some of the computers are on Windows.

Comment: I was under the impression that most commercially available home routers do this for you, provided that you use the built-in DNS proxy as the DHCP/static DNS server for your network.

Comment: The best answer from a similar question: http://askubuntu.com/a/2632/11522

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To resolve [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)) hostnames, other computers should have [libnss-mdns](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libnss-mdns) installed.

Another option, if you are the network administrator is to distribute a private DNS address by DHCP (I your computers are configured by DHCP). For a small network, [dnsmasq](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dnsmasq) is good combined package (DNS+DHCP). It allows you to serve simply your `/etc/hosts` to the network.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libnss-mdns` on the (Ubuntu) computer that you want to share.  This will start the 'Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon' and enable discovery by (hostname).local on computers with compatible client software.

Answer (score 8):

In mixed network environments you can do this with name resolutions from [Avahi/Zeroconfig](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf) that would resolve in Mac-OS as well as in Windows (when [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) is running). See also this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2631/access-ubuntu-server-by-host-name/2632#2632).

Answer (score 6):

In all recent Ubuntu installs you can use `hostname.local` and it just works. I believe this means mDNS is set up automatically, but as it's always just worked (except with some routers in some hotels, where I'd get a notification about it being disabled because of a broken router), I haven't had to dig in.

Answer (score 2):

If you install SAMBA then Windows machines that don't speak mDNS will resolve your hostname using that.

Comment: Excellent suggestion!  Note that from the Windows client, you don't use the ".local" extension.