# Hostname on intranet

Tags: 10.04, server, dns

I have a test server that is running Ubuntu Server in a windows network.

Networking is configured as follows

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
hostname ca
```

the command `cat /etc/hostname` returns `ca`.

But when I use the command `host 10.49.156.196` (its current IP address) from another machine on the network, it returns as follows:

```
196.156.49.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer owner-pc.xxxxx.xxx
```

I can access the machine via SSH and browser using IP address, but not by name `ca`

Any suggestions? I tried installing samba/nmbd as suggested in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2631/access-ubuntu-server-by-host-name), but to no avail.

Comment: Please link to the 'another post' you mentioned.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2631/access-ubuntu-server-by-host-name

Comment: Are you setting `ca` as the hostname in your site/network DNS server?

Comment: i added the line `hostname ca` to `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Is the ca hostname also included in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: Do you control this network?  Or are you just trying to get an automatic discovery service (zeroconf, etc.) working so you don't have to set up name registration?

Comment: I don't control this network. Ca is the hostname in /etc/hostname. My understanding of /etc/hosts is that you would have a line like 127.0.0.1 ca

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the other machines on the network referring to a shared authority, whether it is DNS, synchronized host files, or some other method (e.g., avahi).

The command you are running on the other systems, `host`, is a DNS utility :

> **host** is a simple utility for
>   performing DNS lookups. It is normally
>   used to convert names to IP addresses
>   and vice versa. When no arguments
>   or options are given, host prints a
>   short summary of its command line
>   arguments and options.

As far as the other machines on the network are concerned, it doesn't matter what your machine is referred to locally.  You have to have the host/IP registered to a common system.

Comment: So if you request a hostname from the dhcp server in /etc/network/interfaces, is that not enough?

Comment: @user Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, that won't let other machines access your host by name.   If you're requesting info from the DHCP server, it will usually give you an IP, subnet and default route.  Hostname can also be served to you dynamically or statically, but unless you're using a mechanism you haven't mentioned, the server isn't querying your host or interfaces file for info, it's just responding to a DHCP request.

Comment: I guess I have some reading up to do. Is there a good primer on DNS and DHCP for mixed-OS networks?

Comment: [ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/dhcp.html) and this [DNS How-to](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-2.html) are not bad places to start.   For cross-OS support, look online for a reference for the technology that's already in place on the other OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of other hosts that need to access the server by name, you can simply add a line to each of their /etc/hosts files:

```
10.49.156.196 ca
```

This is really just setting up an alias on each of those machines, but it's far quicker than learning to manage a DNS server and will work on OSX or windows clients as well (\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).